# Whats the most shortest way to echo out a PHP var (in a View) when it exists?

Tags: php

### Problem

I'm trying to shorten this ternary-operator-using PHP statement for usage in View (embedded in HTML).

```
<?php echo (isset($foo) ? $sfoo : ""); ?>
```

The `: ""` annoys me at is has no real purpose here. I've tried around with the Elvis-Operator like `echo (isset($foo) ?: $foo);` but this returns a boolean, not the content of foo.

### Question

How can I achieve to echo out `$foo` if `isset()` is true, in an extremey short way, like above, but without the useless `: ""`-part ? Note: The isset-check is necessary for clean coding and to avoid PHP notices.

Comment: Not possible. Make sure that `$foo` is always set (perhaps to `null`) and life will be much simpler.

Comment: What about <?php echo $foo || null; ?>

Comment: @Leonardo We need the `isset()` check.

Answer (score -2):

You can repress error messages with...

```
<?= @$foo ?>
```

Not the best idea for debugging but as short as you can get the code.

Comment: Not my downvote, but this really is a horrible idea.

Comment: It answers the question... I personally would never use this. Why down vote?

Comment: There are 3 big mistakes in your code: 1. short php tags are really bad style, 2. @-suppresor is really bad style and 3. this does not have an isset()-check. Thanks for your answer, but this does not solve the above problem.

Comment: @Panique: The `<?=` version of short tags is not bad anymore because since 5.4.0 it's always supported. Even when it was not it was a matter of compatibility, not style.

Comment: Thanks @Jon... Can't believe I got down votes... I answered the question... I don't even recommend this in my answer.

Comment: @Gavin Please don't take this personal, I just wanted to "sort" the answers. DVs are nothing against your skill or your personality, it's just a answer-finding process. I'll upvote good answer of you when I see them, deal ?

Comment: @Gavin: It's simply a bad thing to do, so you shouldn't even be bringing it up. It's natural for people to downvote. I would do so as well but decided to leave feedback instead.

Comment: @Panique But that IS the shortest way and a correct answer... whether you or I (and I don't) think it is good practice is another question.

Comment: @Gavin: Fussying about fake internet points is not worth it, and it's not going to make you improve. If you want to play this game then technically this does not answer the question because the question says "echo when it exists", while this answer echos even if the var does not exist. But that's not the point. The answer shows bad practice, code like this is a *bug* and that's why you were downvoted. Learn from it, delete the answer and move on.

Comment: @Jon it does "echo when it exists"